# How do I connect the front audio wires on an Intel mother board?

Tags: motherboard, wiring

I am trying to connect the front audio wires of my cabinet to an Intel D945GCNL motherboard. 
This is how the pinouts are described by Intel:

[image]

These are the wires from the cabinet:

[image]

Can anyone tell which wires go where?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you connecters don't have a presence or sense cable.   It also looks like your mother board does not support a front mic in.  Plug the gray GND cable into the Ground (2) port leave the MIC IN (R) not plugged in.

Plug the front FL and FR into port into port 1 and 3.

Take apart the rear L and R and and plug them into 5 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

insert Line out FR (red color wire) to port 5 and Line out RR (blue color wire) to port 7 and 
insert Line out FL (white color wire) to port 9 and Line out RL (yellow color wire) to port 10

Now go to Realtek HD audio manager and click on device advanced settings. 
In playback device select the 2nd option (make front and rear output devices playback two different audio streams simultaneously)
By doing this you get more clear sound in your head phones when connected to front audio port.